# Is ASCII-only Unicode string always normalized?

Tags: locale, unicode-normalization

Imagine a string of single ASCII character `i` (U+0069). In Turkish and akin writing system, `ı` (U+0131) is present as well. Can Unicode normalization split U+0069 (`i`) into U+0131 U+0307 (`ı̇`)? Is it locale-dependent, and so might vary on environment?

Comment: `U+0307` is well outside the ASCII code range, so the answer to the title question seems like a definitive "yes"

Comment: Normalization is locale independent. But you should never forget that equal looking characters often are not the same (and do not normalize the same). Look A (Latin, Greek, Cyrillic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normali\ation forms defined by Unicode are not locale-specific; they have no input other than the sequence of code points to be normalized.

The Unicode website has [a user-friendly chart](https://www.unicode.org/charts/normalization/) of all characters which differ between the standardized normalization forms.

Unfortunately, it is grouped by *script*, not by *block*, so we can't quickly check all the characters in the "Basic Latin" block (which matches the 128 characters of ASCII).

Searching for "0069" specifically, we see that it appears as the *result* of normalising certain code points - either as part of a "decomposition" in NFD, or as a compatibility replacement in forms NFKC and NFKD. However, it doesn't appear in the *input* column, because it doesn't change when converted *to* any of the normalization forms.

I have not checked the other Basic Latin characters, but would be **extremely** surprised if any of them normalize to anything other than themselves. So to answer your original question: yes, I believe a string that only uses code points U+0000 to U+007F (the code points inherited from the 7-bit ASCII standard) will not change in any of the normalization forms defined by Unicode.